# How to invoke BSD / Gnu Specific Man

Tags: gnu

I have both gnu utilities (via brew) as well as mac default command line tools installed on my Mac.

How do I specify to `man` utility that I want to invoke

- gnu specific tar
- bsd tar

There are my tar locations.

```
$ which -a tar
tar is /usr/local/bin/tar
tar is /usr/bin/tar
```

Comment: If it were me doing it, I would install GNU tar (and its manpage) as `gtar`. No idea if brew does this or can be made to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More likely than not, they're in the same *section* of the manpages, e.g., **`1`**.  But you can get all of the manpages for a given name using the `-a` option, and pick through the result:

```
man -a tar
```

More complicated, you can tell `man` which directories to search using the `-M` option, e.g.,

```
man -M /usr/local/man tar
```

for brew, and

```
man -M /usr/man tar
```

for OSX.

Further reading:

- [man - format and display the on-line manual pages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/man)

Answer (score 1):

With `man`, you can always give an absolute path to a manual page. For the built-in BSD utilities, this will be something like:

```
man /usr/local/share/man/man1/tar.1
```

Now, this isn't particularly convenient, since you have to know the exact path to the page.  For GNU utilities with the same name as built-in BSD utilities, you can note that `brew` installs manual pages in `/usr/local/share/man` with prefixes:

```
# For brew's GNU tar:
man gtar

# For the built-in BSD tar:
MANPATH= man tar
```

The `MANPATH=` part is to reset any changes that may have been made per suggestions by `brew` to ensure that its pages are seen first.